# MonoDevelop throwing an error of 0x80131C30

Tags: mysql, mono, monodevelop, windows-7-x64

I am running MonoDevelop (2.8.6.5) on Windows 7 x64, and have it rendering some pages fine, as well as doing simple MySQL queries.

I now have a problem I would like to debug, however whenever I try to debug I am faced with the following error:

"Debugger Error: The operation failed because debuggee and debugger are on incompatible platforms. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131C30)"

Having done a search online, some suggested that it was to do with me running a 64 bit OS and that I should just compile the application in x86. I have done so, and am still faced with the same error.

Could somebody give me some other suggestions please?

Comment: seems like you are doing something wrong, since i have the same version with the same os and can debug without problem

Comment: Does this help? http://mono.1490590.n4.nabble.com/Debugging-on-Vista-64-Bit-td1516785.html It suggests that you are debugging under .Net rather than mono (if that makes a difference to you)

Comment: 0x80131C30 its mean that debuger's and target program's platform is not same. If debugger x86, create target module x86 too. Read http://community.sharpdevelop.net/forums/t/7274.aspx

Comment: See options here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23328163/unsafe-code-requires-unsafe-command-line-option-to-be-specified-monodevelop-4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that by having MonoDevelop installed, compiling and running C#, does not mean it is running Mono. It will run with .NET until you install Mono, and MonoDevelop cannot debug a .NET app

So ultimately, the solution was to install Mono runtimes, which seemed confusing as it is the Mono IDE, and it compiles and runs Mono code fine, it simply cannot debug without the runtimes.